# No module named ___. How to link Sublime Text3 to a virtual env in python 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, virtualenv

I suppose my sublime text 3 does not see the venv.

I've set up a virtual environment on python 3 via venv. I work in Sublime text 3 on Mac.

When I tried to import non built-in modules like yaml or any other in Sublime I got an error : ImportError: No module named yalm. 
However, the module is properly installed with pip. The venv is activated. I even launch Sublime with the "subl" command from terminal.

running this

```
    import json
    import numpy
    import sys
    import requests

    print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

I get:

```
/Users/maksim/Desktop/py_exercise/code            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

`/Users/maksim/Desktop/py_exercise/code` is my working directory with the venv inside.
And numpy is not installed in my venv.

When I run python in the shell from terminal, it finds modules easily. 
I also have anaconda installed on my machine.

How to link sublime3 to an active virtual env? What is the best practise of that?

Comment: Did you install the module after activating the virtual env? Or is it installed outside of your virtual env?

Comment: I installed after activating. It is installed inside, I checked with "pip list".@BlueSun

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to launch your terminal, activate your environment (venv), and then launch sublime from that prompt

```
$ source venv/bin/activate 
(venv)$ subl .
```

Comment: I tried like that from the beginning. Does not work.

Comment: I found the solution: I installed Virtualenv package. So, every time I launch Sublime I also activate venv inside the Sublime with "Virtualvenv: activate" (in the search).